# IIS Url rewrite username

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite this url in IIS

> mysite.com/profile.aspx?user=foo

to

> mysite.com/foo

This rewrite condition I've tried in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule /foo/(.*) /bar?arg=P1\%3d$1 [R,NE]
```

But how can I do it in IIS Url Rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply:

```
<rule name="Profile Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([^/]+)/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="isFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="isDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="profile.aspx?user={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Note that your Apache rewrite rule won't actually do what you expect at all. Also note that you can easily generate this from the URL Rewrite visual configure tool within IIS Manager.